# How to Export the Value of a Radio Button to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

Okay, so I have a table, some of the columns in that table have radio buttons, which I have marked with values 1 through 10, I also have a 'Export to Excel' button that exports that table to a Excel file, however, when it exports it exports the values of all the radio buttons in each of the columns that have radio buttons, I just want it to export the value of the radio button selected in each column, not the values of all of the radio buttons in each column, oh and BTW the 'Export to Excel' button doesn't work in the preview in Stack Overflow so you'll just have to copy the code if you want that to work and save it as a program on your hard drive, anyways here's my code, thanks for your time to try solving this problem:

```js
    var overall= $('#overall');

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 6) {
    row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
    })

    function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
    }


    });

    var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
    })()
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}   
div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Player</th>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Skating</th>
  <th>Shooting</th>
  <th>Passing</th>
  <th>Puck Control</th>
  <th>Team Play</th>
  <th>Attendance</th>
  <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr class="item" data-id="1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>

</tr>
<tr class="item" data-id="2">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
    </form>
  </td>
<td>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3">3
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4">4
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5">5
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6">6
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7">7
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8">8
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9">9
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10">10
</form>
</td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>

</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div align="center">
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable')" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little hacky but I think I have it working
Notice that I wrapped the text after the radio input in a `span`

what i did was clone the table to a hidden div remove all the unchecked radio buttons then use that for the excel file then remove the cloned item

```js
var overall = $('#overall');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item');
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 6) {
      row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});

var tableToExcel = (function() {
  
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) {
    table = document.getElementById(table)}
    var cloned = $('#copyTable').clone().appendTo('.hidden_table')
    cloned.find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span').remove();
   
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: cloned.html()
    }
    cloned.remove();
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.hidden_table{
/*display:none*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Attendance</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable', 'Player_scores')" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked. I don't really care if its hacky or not as long as it works.

Comment: I'm just wondering, but, when you click the 'Export to Excel' button, the resulting Excel file will have merged two cells together for table cells that are in the 'Team', 'Player',  'Number', & 'Overall' columns which also happen to not contain any radio buttons. However if you don't select any of the radio buttons and export the table to excel it doesn't merge any of the cells together and it will look perfectly fine. Is this a bug or is it a result of the 'hacky' approach you took? Just wondering because it's becoming a little bit annoying.